# MySql calling stored function from within a stored procedure causing error

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064, stored-functions

I'm getting a 1064 error when trying to call a stored function from within a stored procedure.  It only happens on the line where I try to do this: `SET account_id = get_account_id(user);`.  What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Account ID Stored Functions:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`aaron`@`%` FUNCTION `get_account_id`(user VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE xaccount_id INT DEFAULT 0;

   #Get Account ID and place into variable used when calling stored procedure that builds the tree structure for the leaf node portfolio id
    SELECT account_id
    FROM rst_sessions.session_data
    WHERE  username = user
    ORDER BY update_date DESC LIMIT 1
    INTO xaccount_id;

    RETURN xaccount_id;
END
```

Stored Procedure that is trying to call the stored Function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`aaron`@`%` PROCEDURE `build_report_portfolio_list`(user VARCHAR(255))
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

    DECLARE portf_id INT;
    DECLARE portf_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE str_portf_parent_list VARCHAR(455);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE account_id INT;

  SET account_id = get_account_id(user);
END
```

Comment: I don't see the point of the function -- use the query from the function within the stored procedure.  And I though that INTO needed to be before the FROM clause...

Comment: well, I left out the point of the function...the function receives a username and queries a table to retrieve the account_id, then returns that account id back into a variable called account_id, which is then used for another query (the code after the "SET account_id") which I left out for ease of reading...if I comment out the line "SET account_id....." then I don't get any error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't even know if it was possible what I was trying to do, which may have caused the error.  But I found a work around by calling the SF as a parameter with the call to the SP and got it to do what I needed it to do.

Code is: `CALL build_report_portfolio_list(get_account_id('username_here'));`

Comment: what about calling the function inside BEGIN and END?